# Show All Shortcut in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2003, I had a shortcut on the taskbar for "show all".  When I clicked on this button, all the filtered items would open up.  Can someone help me find this shortcut on Excel 2010 so I can add it to the Quick Access Toolbar?

Comment: Doesn't the button Clear on the Data tab this job for you?

Answer (score 3):

This feature has moved to the Data tab of the Excel Ribbon. To add this to the Quick Access Toolbar:

- Click the drop-down arrow on the end of the Quick Access Toolbar
- Choose **More Commands**
- Under **Choose Commands from** select   **Data** Click **Clear** in
  the list and press **Add** Press **OK** to see this button located on
  the Quick Access Toolbar.

[image: quick access toolbar customise excel 2010]

Comment: Glad it helped @ccanitano67! Would you be so kind as to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the old Excel 2003 shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> (for Data->Filter->Show all)

Alternatively, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> will add/remove an AutoFilter. Thus, pressing it twice will reset/clear it, too!